# Create URLs without .php at the end in Apache

Tags: apache, url

I have pages named `help.php`, `about.php` and the address will look like:

```
www.example.com/help.php
```

I would like to convert it to:

```
www.example.com/help/
```

Is there a way to do this without using .htaccess?

Comment: Is there a reason to shun .htaccess?  Or is there just a specific directive to be avoided? Or do we dislike Apache? Would the main vhosts.conf eligible else?

Comment: @Patrioticcow if you have to do this, you can simply create a `help` folder in the webroot and then rename the `help.php` into `index.php` and put it inside the `help` folder. This will most likely do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a folder called help and move help.php into it as index.php. Do the same thing for about. So you end up with:

```
help/index.php
about/index.php
```

Which would both be reachable at just

```
www.example.com/help/
www.example.com/about/
```

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't a way to do this without `.htaccess`.

1. You could change the 'associated extenstion' for php from .php to something like `.p` but you would have to update your apache conf file to reflect that (it would just tell the system that .p files should be treated as `.php` files).
2. Another alternative would be to stick your `help.php` file into `/help/index.php`, which would let you call it as `http://domain.com/help/` as the `index.php` file would be default loaded.

*But that isn't what you were asking for...*

**So short answer is no, cannot be done without** `.htaccess`.